# How to mock TemporaryFile moveTo() method?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, playframework

I'm trying to create a test case for the controller below but I'm encountering some issues that I believe to be related to mocking methods correctly.

#### Issue:

Every time my test runs through this line:

```
file.ref.moveTo(new File(s"${configuration.uploadFileLocation}/$filename").getCanonicalFile,true)
```

It throws the following error:

#### Error:

```
[info] - run test *** FAILED ***
[info]   java.lang.NullPointerException:
[info]   at java.nio.file.Files.provider(Files.java:97)
[info]   at java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1392)
[info]   at play.api.libs.Files$TemporaryFile.moveTo(Files.scala:100)
```

#### Controller:

```
def run = Action.async(parse.multipartFormData) { implicit request =>
  request.body.file("file").map { file =>
    import java.io.File
    val filename = randomFileName
    val contentType = file.contentType
    if (contentType == Some("text/csv")) {
      file.ref.moveTo(new File(s"${configuration.uploadFileLocation}/$filename").getCanonicalFile, true)
      val result = apiClient.match (filename)
      Future.successful("ok")
    } else {
      Future.successful("ok")
    }
  }.getOrElse {
    Future.successful("ok")
  }
}
```

#### Test case:

```
test("run() test") {
  val mockMessageApi = mock(classOf[MessagesApi])
  val mockApiClient = mock(classOf[apiClient])
  val mockConfiguration = mock(classOf[Configuration])
  val mockFile = mock(classOf[File])

  val buildFakeRequest = FakeRequest(POST, "", FakeHeaders(), {
    val tempFile = new TemporaryFile(mockFile)
    val filePart = FilePart("file", "test.file", Some("text/csv"), tempFile)
    MultipartFormData(Map(), List(filePart), List())
  }
  )

  val controller = new MultipleMatch(mockApiClient, mockMessageApi, mockConfiguration)
  val response = controller.run()(buildFakeRequest)
}
```

#### Question:

How can I effectively mock the `ref` and the `moveTo` method? What is causing this to happen? How to avoid the same issue again in the future?